# Celery Flower resets number of processes on restart

Tags: celery, flower

```
celery -A api.worker flower --persistent --db=rclc --max-tasks=10000 --log_file_prefix=C:\temp\flower.log
```

celery version 5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
and flower version 1.2.0

this is how i run my flower, the records in "tasks tab" are consistent with the "dashboard tab" Processes count, but when i restart flower the numbers on the "dashboard tab" are back to zero unlike the in the "tasks tab", the correct number is the "Tasks tabs", is this default or is there i way to make sure they match?
[image: After restart tasks tab]
[image: After restart dashboard tab]

**EDIT:**

i upgraded flower to the latest version 2.0.1, and the same problem still persists.

ill keep testing.

Comment: it's the first time I see the `persistent` (which is cool - I didn't know that!) but seems like it should be: `celery -A api.worker flower --persistent=True --db="rclc" ..` (from the docs). Can you check if that makes a difference?

Comment: this is a good point, although i did try it and it did not work, i even started a new db file but still the records are saved in the tasks bar and not the dashboard after a restart.

Comment: for future visitors, from what i could tell this seems to be a feature and not a bug or an error unfortunately, i hope one day flower creators add an option that resolves this issue.